# I get status 404 back from trello api when adding attachment

Tags: rest, postman, trello

I'm trying to post an attachment to a trello card by a rest call.

[https://api.trello.com/1/cards/617be32c3b22d81055b98c22/attachments&key={{key}}&token={{token}}&defaultLists=false](https://api.trello.com/1/cards/617be32c3b22d81055b98c22/attachments&key=%7B%7Bkey%7D%7D&token=%7B%7Btoken%7D%7D&defaultLists=false)

I'm usign form-data
Key=file Value=filename.jpg

I get status 404 back
and the message:
Cannot POST /1/cards/617be32c3b22d81055b98c22/attachments&key=xxxx&token=yyyy

I have no problems creating a car with the same credentials.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked on trello [api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-attachments-post), then you set up wrong.

- `/1/cards/617be32c3b22d81055b98c22/attachments&key=xxxx&token=yyyy` --> `/1/cards/617be32c3b22d81055b98c22/attachments`
- Move `token` from URL to `form-data`

[image]

One more thing, take care the header `x-trello-reqid`, you cannot use the same `reqid` for next request.

[image]